# Replace tab with space using Bash parameter substitution

Tags: bash, replace

How can I use `${var//Pattern/Replacement}` to replace tab with space?

`${var//\t/ }` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to type an actual TAB character:

```
var=${var// / }
           ^ that's really meant to be a TAB character
             but might not be visible on this site
```

On the command line,
to insert a TAB character,
press <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Answer (score 14):

Adding here since typing an actual tab character through PuTTY into a bash shell is not so simple. `CTRL` `V` `TAB` doesn't work since `CTRL` `V` is captured in windows as paste.

Instead I use:

```
${var//$'\t'/ }
```

Example:

```
$ var="te"$'\t'"st"

$ echo $var
te st

$ echo ${var//$'\t'/i}
teist
```

Comment: Might show `echo "$var"` (actually emitting the tab), vs `echo $var` (string-splitting and so passing each side as a separate argument to `echo`, thus separating only with spaces). Likewise, `echo "${var//$'\t'/i}"` may not fix anything with the current/known value of `var` and a sane IFS, but it's the safer practice for folks to copy from and use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

\t doesn't symolize TAB in bash regex.

```
${var//$(echo -e "\t")/ }
```

Comment: `echo -e` might or might not do what you want. Some implementations may print the "-e" as part of their output. `printf '\t'` is much more portable.

Comment: Not just some implementations, but even bash in some modes (ie. if `xpg_echo` and `posix` runtime flags are set). If you *did* want a command substitution, `printf '\t'` would be more reliable.

Comment: (Also, that's not a "bash regex" -- it's a fnmatch/glob expression).